# NSButton title binding refresh working on 10.12 but not High Sierra 10.13

Tags: macos, cocoa, binding, key-value-observing, macos-high-sierra

I have an NSButton which title is binded to an NSString.

It worked perfectly in 10.12 but in 10.13, the NSButton title is blank on first appearance of the view.

The variable is well assigned and kvo seem to work because as soon as I do the following thing, my title appears:
* Put the whole window in background, or CMD+TAB -> title appears
* Go in another view and come back -> title appears

Just on first time, my button is totally blank, without any title.

I tried [view setNeedsDisplay:] without success.

Comment: Linking to an easy sample project would be really helpful in this case. It's hard to tell where you've set up the initializer code, if anything is nil, etc. I'm not aware of any obvious changes that have been made that would break functionality on the later platform.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a value for "Null Placeholder" in my binding did the trick.

Maybe there's a tiny bug in 10.13 which doesn't trigger an efficient refresh if the binding first meet a Null value, and then the view stay still, atlhough the binding change.

Moving window to background or clicking in the GUI does refresh though.